# How to open a Three.js Project coded with React?

Tags: three.js

I'm new to threejs and relatively new to javascript.
I'm trying to open the code here for 3D Avatar Customisation as a reference:
https://github.com/rubenchoi/react-metaverse

I'm using Visual Code and trying to open the html file with live server but can't get it to open?
They seem to be using React. I have node.js and npm installed the latest as of today.

How am I able to view this work of art?

Comment: you can give a look to [fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber)

Comment: Do you know the steps to use it?